# Query format for Guid filtering with OData Adaptor

Tags: odata, guid

We have bound a table column with Guid field using ODataV4Adaptor. While filtering this field, the query is passed as shown below

http://localhost:49339/odata/Orders/?$count=allpages&$filter=Id%20eq%20guid%27a972c577-dfb0-064e-1189-0154c99310db%27&$skip=0&$top=12

When the query is passed we receive exception as below

Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'guid'a972c577-dfb0-064e-1189-0154c99310da'' at '6' in 'Id eq guid'a972c577-dfb0-064e-1189-0154c99310da''.'

This works fine when guid is removed and passed as

http://localhost:49339/odata/Orders/?$count=allpages&$filter=Id%20eq%20a972c577-dfb0-064e-1189-0154c99310db%20&$skip=0&$top=12

Can anyone suggest me on the proper format to filter guid through query string with OdataV4 adaptor.

Thanks & Regards,

Keerthana.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the single quote in the guid? Use two single quotes instead of the URL encoded `%27`. Example: `guid''a972c577-dfb0-064e-1189-0154c99310da`

Comment: Hi Can you give example how it will work, i tried this :
`Service?$filter=c8e735a52bd94c40b2d32d572eaa6884_Contract_Contractid eq guid''f1c6798a-1b31-4312-a663-a3ec47f06f3c` but is giving me error